# Octave Installation Issue with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, octave

I had installed octave using a simple apt-get command but had to later upgrade it. Going through many links online, I downloaded the latest realease of file directly from website and built it. But it started giving many errors and had to finally purge and remove it.

After that I went for a fresh install by using the repository link to stable octave.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install octave
```

But then it started giving following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
octave is already the newest version (4.0.2-1ubuntu5~octave~xenial1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up octave (4.0.2-1ubuntu5~octave~xenial1) ...
error: couldn't read directory /usr/local/share/octave/packages: No such file or directory
error: called from
    rebuild at line 29 column 7
    pkg at line 505 column 25
dpkg: error processing package octave (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 octave
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Counldnt get octave running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a link and this solved it.

[Re: Error while Compiling octave 4.0 on ubuntu 14.04](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-octave/2016-03/msg00022.html)

We are required to delete old installed octave related files before re-installing to an upgraded version. And then ask Ubuntu to continue with the previous installation.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{bin,include,lib,libexec,share}/octave*
sudo rm -f  /usr/local/bin/mkoctfile*
sudo apt-get -f install
```